# How to re-connect to `bitcoind -printtoconsole` after socket timeout?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

I started `bitcoind` with the option `-printtoconsole` to check for errors and my terminal ssh connection was timed out during the night - probably because my computer was in hibernation.

I see that the process is still running under `top`.

Is there an option to reconnect so that it will print the output to a new ssh connected shell?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can reconnect to it easily, but for next time, you could create a `screen` session and start bitcoind inside of it. That way you could reconnect to it with `screen -r`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reconnect, but everything that is printed with `-printtoconsole` will also be written to the `debug.log` file. So you can just do `tail -f debug.log` to get the same output.

If you wanted to monitor for errors in this way, I would suggest that you always do `tail -f debug.log` instead of using `-printtoconsole`. The debug.log will always be written to so you can look at previous logs while you are offline/away. And it is still written to when Bitcoin Core is daemonized (with `-daemon`) or otherwise running disconnected from your shell (as in your case).